# How can I make FlatList items scrollable when they don't fill the screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, if the items in the FlatList do not fill the screen, the list will not scroll in Android. I need to get the offset Y value for the animation. That's why I want it to be scrollable, even if it's small. How can I make it scrollable in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll only IOS with property `bounces: true`, nothing you can do with Android.

Solution: add view to end of flatlist(make sure height > screen.height)

Comment: Yes, I found a temporary solution by adding padding to the end of the list, but it is not a good idea. The value needs to be dynamic and I don't want to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLayout prop to get the view height instead of the scroll Y offset even though not occurring scroll event.

```
onLayout={e=>{
 console.log('height:', e.nativeEvent.layout.height)
}}
```

Comment: @Jones Beck So, can I know the total height of the components in the list? If I can find out, I can give the required paddingBottom value.